# Accessing the elements of an image in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I wish to access and display the elements of an image in openCV,I am accessing the individual elements with their row and column index and trying to dispaly them in the form of integer on the console,here is my code:

```
            int v=0;
            IplImage* img1 = cvLoadImage("image3.jpg",0);
            Mat img;

            for( int i = 0; i < img.rows; i++)
             {
                for( int j = 0; j < img.cols; j++ )
             {
                v=img.at<uchar>(i,j);

                       cout<<"Value"<<"  "<<v;
             }
            cout<<endl;
             }
            return 0;
```

but I am getting a blank console...
    Where am I going worng???

Answer (score 0):

You loaded the image in `img1` and trying to access elements of `img` which has no data stored. Hence `img.rows` and `img.cols` are both 0 and you get nothing.

Comment: Oooooooooops,my bad:)@Froyo and @Bibek Subedi

Comment: this is not syntax error its logical error so OpenCV doesn't show errors

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Mat img = imread("image3.jpg");
```

In your program img is uninitialized. So you got blank screen

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday I did something like this:

```
IplImage* img = cvLoadImage("image3.jpg", 0);
for( int i = 0; i < img->height; i++)
{
    //ptr - pointer to the first element of each row
    char* ptr = (char*) (img->imageData + i*img->widthStep);

    for( int j = 0; j < img->width; j++ )
    {
        char v = (char) ptr[j];
        cout<< "Value" << "  " << v;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```